# Show a locally bounded Lipschitz function space is compact for sup metric

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

[image]

Just show $\Omega$ = {$f\in\text{Lip}(\alpha,M):|f(u)|\leq M$} is totally bounded and complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just show $\Omega$ = {$f\in\text{Lip}(\alpha,M):|f(u)|\leq M$} is totally bounded and complete.

Note that $\Omega$ is equicontinuous. Given any $\epsilon>0$ and any $x\in S$, there exists a open neighborhood $B(x,\delta,d)=$ {$y\in S:d(x,y)<\delta$} of $x$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq Md(x,y)^\alpha<M\delta^\alpha<\epsilon$ for all $f\in\Omega\subset\text{Lip}(\alpha,M)$. Just let $\delta=(\epsilon/M)^{1/\alpha}/2$.

Since $\Omega$ is equicontinuous, every $f\in\Omega$ is continuous. Since $k$ is compact, by the extreme value theorem, each $f\in\Omega$ is bounded. Thus $\Omega$ is uniformly bounded. By Azela-Ascoi Theorem, $\Omega$ is totally bounded.

$\Omega$ is complete by the following theorem.
[image]