# Class of Lipschitz Functions on the unit d-dimensional ball

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, uniform-convergence, lipschitz-functions, arzela-ascoli

Let $\mathcal{F} = \{f:\mathcal{B}_d \to \mathbb{R}\;:\; \text{f is Lipschitz}\}$, where $\mathcal{B}_d = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^d\;:\: \|x\|_2 \leq 1\}$ is the unit ball in $d$ dimension. Is the class $\mathcal{F}$ finite dimensional?

My approach: For any constant $M$, the set, $\mathcal{F}_M = \{ f \in \mathcal{F}\;:\; \|f\|_\infty \leq M \}$ is compact in the sup norm.
This can be proven the following way
Step 1 : Use Arzela Ascolli to show the $\mathcal{F}_M$ is relatively compact in the uniform norm
Step 2 : Show that this $\mathcal{F}$ is closed in the uniform norm. This means that $\mathcal{F}$ is compact in the unform norm.

The same question have been addressed here, [Show a locally bounded Lipschitz function space is compact for sup metric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3746481/show-a-locally-bounded-lipschitz-function-space-is-compact-for-sup-metric) , so I assume it's true. This is also mentioned in the wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity#Properties.

Question Does this show that the space $(\mathcal{F}, \|\;\|_\infty$ is a locally compact vector space?. The wikipedia page suggests that each $\mathcal{F}_M$ is a locally compact convex set of the Banach Space $\mathcal{C}({\mathcal{B}_d})$

If the space $(\mathcal{F}, \|\;\|_\infty)$ is locally compact, then we can deduce that it must be a finite dimensional space from Riesz Lemma (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F._Riesz%27s_theorem#Statement). The question on the forum [Space of Lipschitz functions is finite dimensional](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4460939/space-of-lipschitz-functions-is-finite-dimensional?rq=1) appears to do this only so I would assume it's true. The only place where it is throwing me off is they have taken $\mathcal{F}$ as a closed subspace of $\mathcal{C}({\mathcal{B}_d})$ such that every $f \in \mathcal{F}$ is Lipschitz. I am not sure how my setup is different? Is my space stritly bigger?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is $\mathcal{F}$ defined for some fixed $M$? By your title, it would seem that you are just talking about all Lipschitz functions and not Lipschitz constant bounded by $M$.

Comment: Assuming $M$ is fixed, $\mathcal{F}$ is not a subspace, since multiplying $f$ by a scalar scales the Lipschitz constant. What does it mean for a set which is not a vector space to be finite dimensional? If $M$ is not fixed, i.e. $\mathcal{F}$ is the space of all Lipschitz functions, then the claim that this space is closed in the sup norm is false; just use Stone-Weierstrass to find a sequence of polynomials which converges uniformly to a continuous, non-Lipschitz function.

Comment: I took inspiration from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4460939/space-of-lipschitz-functions-is-finite-dimensional?rq=1 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3746481/show-a-locally-bounded-lipschitz-function-space-is-compact-for-sup-metric and with your comments I have edited the question. Any further help is appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing yourself about some points. For clarity introduce some notation:

$$\mathcal F_R(L) := \{ f: B\to\Bbb R \mid \forall x,y\in B: |f(x)|\leq R, \ |f(x)-f(y)|\leq L|x-y|\}\\
\mathcal F_R=\bigcup_{L\in\Bbb R}\mathcal F_R(L),\quad \mathcal F(L)=\bigcup_{R\in\Bbb R} \mathcal F_R(L),\quad \mathcal F = \bigcup_{L,R\in\Bbb R}\mathcal F_R(L)$$
So that $\mathcal F$ is the space of all Lipschitz functions from $B$ to $\Bbb R$. Then you have the following:

1. $\mathcal F$ is a vector subspace of $C(B)$. It is **not** closed.
2. $\mathcal F_R$ is the ball of radius $R$ in $\mathcal F$. It is **not** pre-compact: Azerla-Ascoli doesn't apply because the Lipschitz constant can be arbitrarily large, and equicontinuity will then fail.
3. $\mathcal F(L)$ is the space of all Lipschitz functions from $B$ to $\Bbb R$ with Lipschitz constant $\leq L$. This is **not** a vector space, since the implication [$f\in\mathcal F(L)\implies \lambda f\in\mathcal F(L)$ for all $\lambda\in\Bbb R]$ **fails**.
4. $\mathcal F_R(L)$ **is** pre-compact by Azerla-Ascoli.

Your strategy of showing finite dimensionality of any of the spaces will then not succeed. For $\mathcal F$ (or its closure) it doesn't work because $\mathcal F$ is not locally compact, because the balls in $\mathcal F$ are not pre-compact. For $\mathcal F(L)$ the "balls" $\mathcal F_R(L)$ are pre-compact, but $\mathcal F(L)$ is not a vector subspace.

Comment: In your notation can you explain (either as a comment or as an edit to the the answer) how this works then https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4460939/space-of-lipschitz-functions-is-finite-dimensional

Comment: If $V$ is a subspace of $\mathcal F$ that is **closed** in $C(B)$, the answer finds an open subset of $V$ that is pre-compact, wlog you can take this subset to be a ball around some point. Since you can translate and scale this set without changing the property of pre-compactness you get that $V$ is locally compact. Essential to the proof is applying Baire, which needs $V$ to be **complete**. $V$ is only complete if it is closed in $C(B)$, a condition that fails for $\mathcal F$.

Comment: The statement in the question you linked can be summarized as "if $W\subseteq \mathcal F$ is a subspace then $\overline W$ (the closure in $C(B)$) is contained in $\mathcal F$ if and only if $W$ is finite dimensional".

Comment: So essential $\bar{W}$ contains elements of $\mathcal{F}$ if and only if $W$ is finite dimensional. I still feel confused about requiring the closure in $\mathcal{C}(B)$. Does this mean $\bar{W}$ will contain some elements of $C(B)$ as well and only if it is finite dimensional that it will contain truly just functions from $\mathcal{F}$?

Comment: $\overline W$ contains $W$, which is contained in $\mathcal F$, so $\overline W$ will always have some elements of $\mathcal F$. But unless $W$ is finite dimensional it will also have elements that do not belong to $\mathcal F$.